# List chapters of a book from a public books API?

Tags: web-services, api, rest, amazon-web-services, google-books

Anyone knows of a web service where I could get either the number of chapters or list the chapter names of a book?

I've checked Google Books API and couldn't find this info.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the Open Librayr API: https://openlibrary.org/dev/docs/api/books

The `jscmd=details` query parameter might be of use for you, since it returns a table of contents.

Comment: Thanks. It was really helpful, though it's not normalized. I can't assure every book will have an array of contents. I guess such service might not exist at all and I will have to figure out a workaround.

Comment: I need that same service @javorosas, did you make any progress?